# Query size exceeded 20000 bytes

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After reading MySQL documentation I'm very lost, I have the following error while trying to import SQL file with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld --user=mysql --bootstrap --verbose=0 --skip-name-resolve --skip-networking=0 \< myfile.sql
```

The error message is Boostrap file error.

> Query size exceeded 20000 bytes near ...

I try to modify max_allowed_packet but the problem is still here

Comment: You should start mysqld normally and then use mysqlimport to load the data into a running server instead of trying to bootstrap a server with such a large init file.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, do you know if there are a solution to modify the 20000 bytes limits? I will try to use mysqlimport

Comment: Importing SQL files should be done with the `mysql` client, not the `mysqld` server. See examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/8.0/en/batch-mode.html